# Does Runtime.exec() work only for certain commands?

Tags: java, cmd, runtime-error

So I want to use the windows tree's command to display the a hierarchy graphical representation of all the files present in a directory.

But when I run the command,

`Process cmd=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tree \"path\" /f /a");`

I get this error,

`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "tree": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

Does `java.lang.Runtime.exec(String command)` only work for certain commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program you're trying to execute is called `tree.com`.

It is the command-line interpreter `cmd.exe` that uses the `PATHEXT` environment variable to search the path for programs with various extensions. Java's API doesn't.

So you have 2 choices:

- Add the extension:

  ```
  Process cmd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tree.com \"path\" /f /a");
  ```
- Run it using `cmd.exe`:

  ```
  Process cmd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c tree \"path\" /f /a");
  ```

The `.exe` extension is optional, e.g. `"cmd /c tree \"path\" /f /a"` works too, but any other extension (e.g. `.com`) is required, and scripts (`.bat`, `.cmd`) must be run with `cmd.exe`.